# How to get "n+1" as output if my variable has "n" numbers in it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string variable with the following data.

```
string str = string.Empty;
if ("my condition")
{
str = list[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

where `i` is the number of lines in a text file and

```
list[0]="Step 1:Some text"
list[1]="continuation of the text in step1"
list[2]="Step 2:Some text"
list[3]="continuation of the text in step2"
list[4]="Step 3:Some text"
list[5]="continuation of the text in step3"
```

When I print the `str` variable I get all the steps. In addition to this I have to append a message to it. I am using the following console code,

```
string error = str + Environment.NewLine + "Step 4:Some text";
```

Now instead of using `Step 4:` directly, is there any way to count the number of Steps and generate the next number and store it in a varable? Will`Split()` function be used in this scenario.

Comment: `list.size() / 2`?

Comment: I don't find your description that clear. Can you add an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Is a simple (list.Length / 2) + 1 not enough?   If the "continuation" steps could be multiple then you can call a method to count the occurrences of "step".  Maybe using Linq.

Comment: don't build string that way, at least use a `StringBuilder` or even better here simply use `string.Join (Environment.NewLine, list)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use Linq:

```
var stepCount = list.Count(text => text.StartsWith("Step")) + 1;
//C#6
var error = $"{str}{Environment.NewLine}Step {stepCount.ToString()}:Some text";
//Or C# before version 6
var error = string.Format("{0}{1}Step {2}:Some text", str, Environment.NewLine, stepCount.ToString());
//Or use StringBuilder
var error = new StringBuilder().AppendLine(str).Append("Step ")
    .Append(stepCount.ToString()).Append(":SomeText").ToString();
//Or plain old string concat
var error = str + Environment.NewLine + "Step " + stepCount.ToString() + ":Some text";
```

Comment: `Count` has an overload to only count the items where the specified predicate holds, so you don't need the Where : `1 + list.Count (txt => txt.StartsWith ("Step"))`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You are certainly right, and I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works fine.